# no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, overriding, vtk

I'm trying to use vtk in my code, but I'm having problems running an example. I have almost no clue about the reasons since it's the first time I'm using it and I'm not very experienced. 
I'm using visual studio 2012 and x64 platform.
Since I don't really know which libs should I use I added all of them to the "Additional Dependencies".
The example is given in [this link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Cylinder).
The problem is that when I run it, the window shows this message

```
Generic Warning: In C:\location\VTK6.0.0\Rendering\Core\vtkPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 27
Error: no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'.
```

which corresponds to this line

```
// Return NULL if no override is supplied.
vtkAbstractObjectFactoryNewMacro(vtkPolyDataMapper)
```

And the error that visual studio shows is

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007F7AA106C8F in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or at least what does this error mean?

Comment: Have you compiled your project using CMake? If not, it could be the reason...Integrating VTK with VS is not a short task...Check [this guide](http://guitarcplusplus.blogspot.it/2013/02/itk-vtk-qt-on-window-7-64bit-and-visual.html) to see what I'm talking about (I know, it's about VS2010 and the previous version of VTK...And you  can skip Qt's and ITK's parts as well...)

Comment: yes, I did compile it. I didn't check the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS though because I prefer to use static ones.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I too was getting this error. The error means that the linker can't find the definition for the vtkPolyDataMapper method. One has to note which vtk rendering backend they used, during build. It will probably be either vtkRenderingOpenGL, or vtkRenderingOpenGL2. Go to your build/lib folder and search for either one of these. I have VS 2015 Community and had the vtkRenderingOpenGL2, with vtk-7.1 built on Windows 8.1, x86_64 Platform, Release configuration.

I fixed the issue by inserting the 3 following lines at the very top of my source files, before any other preprocessor directives:

```
#include "vtkAutoInit.h" 
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2); // VTK was built with vtkRenderingOpenGL2
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

This initializes the specified VTK modules. CMake includes these by default, but other compilers such as VS do not.

The last two lines can be combined into the following:

```
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingOpenGL2, vtkInteractionStyle)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes the problem since I stopped having it after updating to a newer version. If someone is able to test it, please comment below.

Comment: `#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingOpenGL, vtkInteractionStyle)` worked for me for VTK 8.1

Answer (score 14):

According to the [VTK migration guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines), if you are not using CMake to compile your code, you need to add some `#define`s. For VTK 6.0, these lines need to go **before** any other VTK `#include`s:

```
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 4(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL,vtkRenderingOpenGL)
#define vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT 1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing `include(${VTK_USE_FILE})` in your CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your are using OpenGL2, you should initialise the `vtkRenderingOpenGL2` module, ensuring its object factory is correctly registered:

```
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
```

You should call this macro in the global scope (ex. `main.cpp`) as [documented in the source code](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkAutoInit_8h_source.html):

> Initialize the named module, ensuring its object factory
>   is correctly registered and unregistered. This call must be made in
>   global scope in the translation unit of your executable (which can
>   include a shared library, but will not work as expected in a static
>   library).
>
> ```
> #include "vtkAutoInit.h"
> VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);
> ```
>
> The above snippet if included in the global scope will ensure the
>   object factories for `vtkRenderingOpenGL` are correctly registered and
>   unregistered.

**How do you know which module to include?**

The easiest method is to search in the VTK build folder for `"vtkClassThatNeedsAnOverride"`, i.e. `"vtkPolyDataMapper"` in your case (note the use of quotes `"`.) and looking for a `*ObjectFactory` in your search results:

> Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkRenderingOpenGL2ObjectFactory.cxx:
>
> ```
> this->RegisterOverride("vtkPolyDataMapper",
>                        "vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper",
>                        "Override for vtkRenderingOpenGL2 module", 1,
>                        vtkObjectFactoryCreatevtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper);
> ```

It may be even more beneficial to look for `RegisterOverride("vtkPolyDataMapper"`.

**Which object factories exist?**

To obtain a list of all existing modules that you could initialise, you can search for `_AutoInit_Construct`. `*_AutoInit_Construct` is the method that is called by `VTK_MODULE_INIT`.

As an alternative, you can look at all classes that derive from [`vtkObjectFactory`](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkObjectFactory.html).

A second alternative is to look for all calls to [`RegisterOverride`](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkObjectFactory.html#a8466fa22fcf9a907d8d46a459dda4f5c).

**Further information**

- [VTK 6 Migration: Factories now require defines](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines)
- [Build System Migration](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration): You do not need to call `VTK_MODULE_INIT` manually using **cmake** by calling `include(${VTK_USE_FILE})` in your `CMakeLists.txt`

*Note that I originally wrote this answer for a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595367/no-override-found-for-vtkimageslicemapper?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I think the general information about solving this problem may be of interest for other people with the same error message.*

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend following the guide [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines), with the VTK_MODULE_INIT macro being the most reliable, with [the guide here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration) providing a high level overview of the changes needed. You must link to vtkRenderingOpenGL for example to get most of the standard overrides. If you use CMake then specifying it on the COMPONENTS argument to find_package would cause it to be added to VTK_LIBRARIES, and including VTK_USE_FILE would cause the correct compiler definitions to be added.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue at my platform;
Visual Studio 2015
Windows 7
VTK 6.3

I followed [VTK/Build System Migration](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration#How_Implementation_Modules_Are_Initialized) from Marcus D. Hanwell's post, and it works. My additonal lines are;

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

on the top of preprocessor. The difference from RestlessC0bra's post is probably OpenGL version.

Answer (score 1):

When using ParaView's Catalyst libraries you have to add the following in addition to `include("${PARAVIEW_USE_FILE}")`:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${VTK_DEFINITIONS})
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack solution: In CMakeList.txt file, replace **vtkRendering${VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND}** with **vtkRenderingOpenGL2.** The reason why we need this is because Cmake does not know where the rendering core is. By specifying it, we can use the rendering core to override the proper method.

The proper solution should be replace the whole find_package paragraph with:

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED COMPONENTS vtkCommonCore) 
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS 
   vtkFiltersSources
   vtkInteractionStyle
   vtkRendering${VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND})
```

The first find_package lets the CMake know where to find the packages, then  second find_package would know where to find **vtkRendering${VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND}**.