# C++ [vtkusers] VTK 7.0.0 problems: SimplePointsReader! why it does not work in my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vtk

I'm trying to use VTK in my code, but I'm being in trouble. I donot know how to fix it, and I'm not experienced.

I'm using VTK 7.0.0, visual studio 2012 and X64 platform, and the code is copy [the link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/SimplePointsReader). PLUS: my operating system is win7 x64.

If i build my project with CMake, and i made it. But there is fail when i new a project in VS 2012, and I change *Additional Include Directories* and *Additional Library Directories* in right way.

I also find [the simple queation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642155/no-override-found-for-vtkpolydatamapper) and [the guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Factories_now_require_defines), and I know there is missing marco for SimplePointsReader or update(), I cannot figure out.

I have add:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2);
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

But it doesnot work. Does anyone know how to solve this problem or at least what does this error mean?

Comment: What error do you get when you build with VS2012?

Comment: It's ok when I build, but its error when i run the project.

Comment: The vtkOutPutWindow is say ERROR: In F:\VTK-7.0.0\IO\Legacy\vtkSimplePointsReader.cxx, line 63
vtkSimplePointsReader (00000000002A65B0): Error opening file simple.xyz

ERROR: In F:\VTK-7.0.0\Common\ExecutionModel\vtkExecutive.cxx, line 784
vtkCompositeDataPipeline (00000000002A1400): Algorithm vtkSimplePointsReader(00000000002A65B0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (00000000002A3A80)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 113
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Request: REQUEST_DATA
  ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
  FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0
  FROM_OUTPUT_PORT: 0