# VTK and QT debugging in VS

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

After lots of trouble I finally managed to set up VTK with QT using Visual Studio. The setup was done using cmake.

The versions I use are:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Qt 5.6.2
- VTK 8.0.0

My first goal was to be able to run examples like [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/SideBySideViewports).

I'm able to run that examples and others in Release mode in VS and correctly run the executables.

The problem is when I set it to Debug Mode I will end up with an Error:

```
The program '[9520] SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

After a few tries I found out that in Debug mode, whenever a QVTKWidget is created:

```
QVTKWidget *qvtkWidgetLeft;
(...)
qvtkWidgetLeft = new QVTKWidget(centralwidget);
```

I get the above error.

I've set up a debugger in QTcreator following this post [How to configure CDB in Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975949/how-to-configure-cdb-in-qt-creator)

**EDIT:**

The callstack if it helps:

```
>   SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.exe!QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>::QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>(int * __formal) Line 112 C++
    SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.exe!Ui_SideBySideRenderWindowsQt::setupUi(QMainWindow * SideBySideRenderWindowsQt) Line 72    C++
    SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.exe!SideBySideRenderWindowsQt::SideBySideRenderWindowsQt() Line 19    C++
    SideBySideRenderWindowsQt.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 9  C++
```

**EDIT 2: Example**

This example is from generating a new project of type **QT GUI Application** in Visual Studio 2013

See the comments in `ui_QtGuiApplication.h`

**main.cpp**

```
#include "QtGuiApplication2.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtGuiApplication2 w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**QtGuiApplication2.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication2.h"

class QtGuiApplication2 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication2(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication2Class ui;
};
```

**QtGuiApplication2.cpp**

```
#include "QtGuiApplication2.h"

QtGuiApplication2::QtGuiApplication2(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

**ui_QtGuiApplication.h**

*This file is generated after using QT Design via Visual Studio:*

```
#ifndef UI_QTGUIAPPLICATION2_H
#define UI_QTGUIAPPLICATION2_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_QtGuiApplication2Class
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QVTKWidget *qvtkWidget;   //Generated after adding VTK Widget
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *QtGuiApplication2Class)
    {
        if (QtGuiApplication2Class->objectName().isEmpty())
            QtGuiApplication2Class->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("QtGuiApplication2Class"));
        QtGuiApplication2Class->resize(600, 400);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(QtGuiApplication2Class);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));

        //THE LINES BELOW ARE GENERATED IF I 
        //ADD A VTK WIDGET FROM QT DESIGN:
        //In Debug mode, the first line returns:
        //The program '[15392] QtGuiApplication2.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
        //In Release mode, the program works fine.
        qvtkWidget = new QVTKWidget(centralWidget);
        qvtkWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("qvtkWidget"));
        qvtkWidget->setGeometry(QRect(200, 100, 100, 100));


        QtGuiApplication2Class->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(QtGuiApplication2Class);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 600, 21));
        QtGuiApplication2Class->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(QtGuiApplication2Class);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mainToolBar"));
        QtGuiApplication2Class->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(QtGuiApplication2Class);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusBar"));
        QtGuiApplication2Class->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(QtGuiApplication2Class);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QtGuiApplication2Class);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *QtGuiApplication2Class)
    {
        QtGuiApplication2Class->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("QtGuiApplication2Class", "QtGuiApplication2", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class QtGuiApplication2Class: public Ui_QtGuiApplication2Class {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_QTGUIAPPLICATION2_H
```

Comment: Why you use QtCreator for debugging if you're setting the project in Visual Studio? Use the visual studio debugger. When it crashes check the callstack. It seems something like a invalid pointer somewhere but from your post I can't confirm it.

Comment: I don't want to debug with QT creator. After searching for a solution I thought I had to setup a debugger in qtcreator to correctly debug from VS. I might be wrong. But anyway I run the default VS debugger. I will check what the callstack says.

Comment: Qt Creator setup is indeed irrelevant if you use Visual Studio. Posting the stack may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Done.

Comment: The program does not crash in the constructor of `QVTKWidget`. What is written in `setupUi` on line 72?

Comment: @m7913d qvtkWidgetLeft = new QVTKWidget(centralwidget); is line 72.

Comment: Stepping into it, it jumps directly to: `Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags(Zero = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : i(0) {}` in `qFlag` class, followed by returning to line 72.. (I guess this comment got a bit messy, but let me know if I can give you some info...)

Comment: Can you construct a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes I should do that. But first time I use VTK and QT, and everything is a bit confusing. Since this works fine when building in Release but not in Debug, I was hoping someone has encountered a similar problem.

Comment: @m7913d I've added an example

Comment: Is it a minimal example? Will `void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {QApplication a(argc, argv); QVTKWidget *pWidget = new QVTKWidget(); a.exec();}` also result in a crash? Note that a minimal example will help us to localise the problem.

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer to the question. Found at last a solution. But yes I believe it should run and crash if QT and VTK are correctly setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to my own problem**

As I already had built VTK in both Debug and Release mode I thought that was in order.

But I saw in the output that my solution was getting the dll files from `...\VTK\VTK-bin\bin\Release\` which was added in Environment variables as a `PATH`.

I solved this by also adding `...\VTK\VTK-bin\bin\Debug\`.

In environment variables under the `PATH` i know have:

```
C:\VTK\VTK-bin\bin\Debug
C:\VTK\VTK-bin\bin\Release
```

As Debug is listed first, it will get the dlls from this folder now, and I can correctly run in debug mode. (Atm the moment I need to switch the order of these two variables if I want to build in Release mode, so would still have to find a better solution for how the project finds the dlls.)

*An additional problem that happened for me was a new error, it is described here:
[no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642155/no-override-found-for-vtkpolydatamapper) ,
and as stated in the solution it was resolved by adding:*

```
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 2(vtkRenderingOpenGL2, vtkInteractionStyle)
```

*in the beginning of QVTKwidget.h*